# .htaccess return error if no RewriteRule meets the request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying my hands on writing a simple REST API and am currently trying to properly configure my `.htaccess` file.

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

- have `RewriteRule`s to direct requests towards the actual RestController
- catch all requests not explicitly served with a `RewriteRule` before with a FITTING error

  - requests that target any file, subdirectory or file in subdirectory not handled with a former `RewriteRule` should be answered `403`
  - requests that target any non-existent file or subdirectory should be answered `404`

What I have achieved up until now is:

- ✅ serving non-existent files, subdirs and files in subdirs `404`
- ✅ serving existing files and subdirs without proper `RewriteRule` `403`
- ❌ forwarding valid API requests to the proper endpoint (it stopped working after I added the last `403` rule)
- ❌ serving `403` for existing files IN SUBDIRS without proper `RewriteRule` - eg. when I try to access `domain.com/subdir/existingfile.pdf`, it actually shows the file, which I don't want.

**Since subdirs may be created dynamically, I want ALL subdirs and files in them to be handled 403 without having to manually specify them.**

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# REST mappings
RewriteRule ^json$   RestController.php?key=json [L,nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$   RestController.php?key=file&id=$1 [L,nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^actions$   RestController.php?key=actions&id=none [L,nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^actions/(.*)$   RestController.php?key=actions&id=$1 [L,nc,qsa]

# catch all non-matched requests and throw 404 or 403 accordingly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `RestController.php` is a file and not one of your "mappings", the last rule will *unconditionally* serve a 403.

You need to either, make an exception for `RestController.php` and/or use the `END` flag (new in Apache 2.4), instead of `L`, to prevent all further processing of the mod_rewrite directives. (The `L` flag only stops the current round of processing. In a *directory* context, like `.htaccess`, the rewritten URL is passed to the next phase of processing and the last rule is then processed during the second phase.)

You also don't need an explicit rule to serve the 404, since that will happen by default. You only need a rule when the request maps to a file (or directory) in order to serve a 403.

For example, with an exception for `RestController.php` in the last rule block:

```
:

# catch all non-matched requests and throw 404 or 403 accordingly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !^RestController\.php$ - [R=403]

# A 404 will naturally be served otherwise...
```

You don't need the `L` flag when using a non-3xx status with the `R` flag.

You don't necessarily need to check for a directory (2nd condition), unless you happen to have a `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.php` or `index.html`) in that directory (but why would you?). A 403 is served automatically by mod_autoindex when requesting a directory with no `DirectoryIndex` document.

Alternatively, or as well as, use the `END` flag in the preceding rules:

```
# REST mappings
RewriteRule ^json$ RestController.php?key=json [END,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) RestController.php?key=file&id=$1 [END,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^actions$ RestController.php?key=actions&id=none [END,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^actions/(.*) RestController.php?key=actions&id=$1 [END,NC,QSA]

# catch all non-matched requests and throw 404 or 403 accordingly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]

# A 404 will naturally be served otherwise...
```

The `NC` flag should not be necessary here. Note also that I removed the `$` in `^file/(.*)$` since it's not required (regex is greedy by default).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> # REST mappings
> RewriteRule ^json$ RestController.php?key=json [END,NC,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^file/(.*) RestController.php?key=file&id=$1 [END,NC,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^actions$ RestController.php?key=actions&id=none [END,NC,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^actions/(.*) RestController.php?key=actions&id=$1 [END,NC,QSA]
> ```

Your "mappings" could be reduced to a single rule if you standardise the endpoints, ie. Always a `key` and `id` parameter and `id` could be *empty* (not "none"), which you would need to validate for anyway (both `/actions` and `/actions/` are valid requests according to your rules, but result in different targets). You then validate the target in your PHP script.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(json|file|actions)(?:/(.*))?$ RestController.php?key=$1&id=$2 [END,NC,QSA]
```

This does mean that `/json/<foo>` and `/file` would be successfully rewritten to `RestController.php` (which would otherwise be ignored by your original rules), but these requests should be handled by your REST API validation anyway. Perhaps `.*` should really be `.+`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for that detailed explanation! I learned a lot about .htaccess today. To be honest, I just cobbled together a few pieces from the web while trying to understand what they do from the documentation... I can't believe I didn't think about the php file actually being a FILE. I went with your suggestion to change the bottom block and (almost) everything does what I wanted and I'm sure I can handle the rest. Thanks again!